# Get undefined value in Javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript

```
var sockets = [];

function findSocketByUID(uid){
  var index = findIndexByUID(uid);

  if(index == -1)  return null;
  return sockets[index];
}


socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  if(msg.to == 'all'){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  }else{
    var socket_to = findSocketByUID(msg.to);
    if(socket_to){
      socket_to.emit("chat message", msg);
    }else{
      socket.broadcast.emit("chat message", msg);
    }
  }
});
```

Hi, this is part of my Node.JS application, 
findSocketByUID is called with an argument msg.to, which is a string value.
But why parameter uid in function findSocketByUID is undefined? How do I call findSocketByUID correctly to pass an argument?

Edit:
I add a breakpoint at this line:

```
var socket_to = findSocketByUID(msg.to);
```

and my msg looks like this:

> "{
>     "to" : "a27efd3f-ee63-413a-20ae-527419fab246",
>     "content" : "giuh",
>     "time" : "2016-06-06T11:27:11Z",
>     "from" : "683C2782-A575-4154-9F78-CAD6B74AB19D"
>   }"

Comment: Yes, I add a breakpoint using node inspector, and msg.to is actually a valid string representing a user.

Comment: Yes, when step into the function, uid becomes undefined. wired.

Comment: Thank you, that's the reason. I forgot to parse the JSON string.

Comment: You should try @nnnnnn suggestion. He seems right.

Comment: @nnnnnn, if you post your comment as answer, I will mark it correct. thanks.

Comment: Done. I've deleted my previous comments, because your edit and my answer have made them redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msg` shown in your edit seems to be a string of JSON, not an actual object (it has quote marks outside the curly brackets). A string won't have a `.to` property.

You'll need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an actual object so that you can access its properties.